# syntax error when using ConditionalFreqDist

Tags: python

I am trying to get the ConditionalFreqDist but Python keeps giving me a syntax error on the third line (for category in ..). I can't figure out the problem, any ideas (I'm a beginner).

```
 def persoonlijkvnw(mijn_corpus):
    cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(category,word)
    for category in mijn_corpus.categories()
    for word in mijn_corpus.words(categories=category)
    category = mijn_corpus.categories()
    persoonlijke_vnw = ['ik','jij','hij','wij','jullie','zij']
    cfd.tabulate(conditions=category, samples=persoonlijke_vnw)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for information on basic syntax you should probably refer to a Python tutorial.

I'll quote the official documentation on [compound statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html):

> Compound statements consist of one or more ‘clauses.’ A clause consists of a header and a ‘suite.’ The clause headers of a particular compound statement are all at the same indentation level. Each clause header begins with a uniquely identifying keyword and **ends with a colon**. A suite is a group of statements controlled by a clause. A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be **one or more indented statements on subsequent lines**. Only the latter form of suite can contain nested compound statements

(Emphasis is mine).

As you can see from the same page, a `for` loop also [is a compound statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), and since in your case the "suites" are not on the same line as "headers", they should be indented. Also, a colon is needed at the end of the "header".

Without the indentation, we cannot say where the loop bodies end, but what I mentioned are probably only parts of the problems with this code.

For example, the `category` variable is used as the outer loop counter, but is reassigned in the loop. This is not a syntax error, but may or may not be an oversight by the author.